# Process XML tags and extract corresponding tag content

Tags: python, html, xml, python-3.x

The contents of the processed XML file are as follows:

```
<dblp>
<incollection>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<author>Philippe Balbiani</author>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
<author>Valentin Goranko</author>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
<author>Ruaan Kellerman</author>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
<author>Dimiter Vakarelov</author>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
<booktitle>Handbook of Spatial Logics</booktitle>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
</incollection>
<incollection>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
<author>Jochen Renz</author>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
<author>Bernhard Nebel</author>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
<booktitle>Handbook of AI</booktitle>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
</incollection>
...
</dblp>
```

The format content is as shown above extracting the "author" tag content and the "booktitle" tag content which are all in the "incollection" tag traversing each "incollection" tag and letting multiple author tag contents form a "booktitle" tag content.  a corresponding relationship

my code:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(getfile()), 'lxml')
res = soup.find_all('incollection') 
list = []
list1=[]

for each in res:
    for child in each.children:
          if child.name == 'author':
                list.append(child.text)

          if child.name == 'booktitle':
                list1.append(child.text)           
                elem_dic = tuple(zip(list, list1))
```

My result is:

```
('Philippe Balbiani', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics')
('Valentin Goranko', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics')
('Ruaan Kellerman', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics')
```

The ideal result is as follows:

```
('Philippe Balbiani', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics')
('Valentin Goranko', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics')
('Ruaan Kellerman', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics')
('Dimiter Vakarelov', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics')
('Jochen Renz', 'Handbook of AI')
('Bernhard Nebel', 'Handbook of AI')
```

How can I modify it to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Don't use `list` as variable. `list` is built-in function. Change it to anything like `list1, list2`.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code as given below,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(getfile()), 'lxml')
res = soup.find_all('incollection') 
author = []
booktitle =[]

for each in res:
    for child in each.children:
          if child.name == 'author':
                author.append(child.text)
          elif child.name == 'booktitle': # either it will be 'author' or 'booktitle' so use 'elif'
                booktitle.append(child.text)           
elem_dic = tuple(zip(author, booktitle)) # No need to assign in every loop as you are already storing in lists
```